# Adding a second Y axis to an LTSpice plot

Tags: ltspice, probe

I am new to using LTSpice and am coming over from using Cadence.  In Cadence you can add a second Y axis.  Plot-> Add Y Axis is the probe pane in Cadence.  Is there a way to do this in LTSpice?

Comment: Right click, add plot plane and then drag your signal to your new plot plane.

Comment: It put a second y-axis with a different plot scale to the left of the first one.  During my time at university I used a book by a man named Marc Herniter.  In the book he shows how you would add a second Y-axis.  I was never sure why you would need to do this but he does. I was just wondering if there was a way to do it in LTSpice

Comment: For complex data, you can choose to plot either phase, group delay, or nothing against the right vertical axis. You can change the representation of complex data from Bode to Nyquist or Cartesian by moving the mouse to the left vertical axis of complex data.

Answer (score 1):

LTSpice automatically does this, simply by adding a probe point with different units (right click / add trace or single click on node of interest).  The image below, for example, probes a dc voltage sweep on the primary (left) y-axis and a current response on the secondary (right) y-axis.  This is useful if you want to plot two quantities of interest (different units) vs a single variable.

[image]

If you mean a secondary plot pane, you can click on add plot pane and probe the next quantity of interest (can add several also).

[image]

Comment: I was interested in the first situation.  Thanks.